# Count lists inside a list recursively

Tags: python, list, recursion, count

Let's assume we have lists with different amount of sublists and want to count the sublists recursively

```
Example 1: l1 = [['a', 'bb'], ['c', 'a']] => count two sublists
Example 2: l2 = [[['c', 'x'], ['g', 'ad']], [['a', 'bb'], ['c', 'a']]] => count six sublists
```

There are already several threads on this topic: [non recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747524/count-duplicate-lists-inside-a-list) or [for elements in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455612/how-to-count-items-in-list-recursively). Still I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic solution than to call a recursive function and check each time if element is a list.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: You could use `len()` right? Or do you want another way for it?

Comment: @PCM len(l2) is 2 right?

Comment: @KlausD. Please show me where my question is a duplicate? Can you apple the cited references to my example and get the correct answer?

Comment: You linked the duplicates yourself. They have valid solutions for the problem. It is just that you are not happy with them for being not "pythonic" enough, which is a very subjective term. You will have to come up with a solid criteria and explain why you need that for other than personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only are interested in the number of sublists, you could do this:

```
print(str(l2).count('[')-1)

# 6
```

**Speed:**

*2.04 µs ± 139 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)*

*under the assumption that those brackets are not part of the value of a sublist

Comment: Actually this is quiet a nice one, don't know why somebody disliked it!

Comment: @JürgenK. thank you, I was also confused. There is of course the limitation of having no `[ ` in a sublist, otherwise the logic gets screwed, but if that is a given, speed and readbility are rather good in my oppinion. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this should not be recommended as a valid approach. It circumvents the algorithmic challenge (passes it on to the `str` and provides little insight for beginners) and depends on the grace of the actual data.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, I think you have three valid points, but OP has referenced the 'best practice' approaches already. (i) A beginner could therefore find the 'cleaner' alternatives rather easily. (ii) The algorithmic challenge was skipped, True, because it was already adressed in different other SO-questions. (iii) data dependence is therefore the most crucial critique point and you are absolutely right. I think this is a niche solution, but that is was OP was asking for in my point of view.

Answer (score 3):

You can try sth along these lines:

```
def rec_len(obj):
    return sum(1 + rec_len(e) for e in obj if isinstance(e, list))

rec_len([[['c', 'x'], ['g', 'ad']], [['a', 'bb'], ['c', 'a']]])
# 6
```

Or non-recursive, using a stack:

```
def iter_len(obj):
    total, agenda = 0, obj[:]
    while agenda:
        x = agenda.pop()
        if isinstance(x, list):
            total += 1
            agenda.extend(x)
    return total
```

You will have to do type checking of some sort, if simply to differentiate lists from other iterables like strings.

Comment: Thanks, for giving both a recursive and an iterative solutions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution to your problem of list counting:

```
def list_counter(list_, count=0):
    for x in list_:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            count += 1
            count = list_counter(x, count=count)
    return count
```

Example:

```
l1 = [['a', 'bb'], ['c', 'a']]
l2 = [[['c', 'x'], ['g', 'ad']], [['a', 'bb'], ['c', 'a']]]
print(list_counter(l1))
print(list_counter(l2))

>>> 2
>>> 6
```

Comment: Thanks. I described a solution like this in my question and was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Why did you choose to make `count` an optional argument rather than an internal variable? I think it would be less confusing as an interval variable, adding `count = 0` at the beginning, and replacing `count += 1; count = list_counter(x, count=count)` with `count += 1 + list_counter(x)`

Comment: You could also replace the whole body of `list_counter` with `return sum(1 + list_counter(x) for x in list_ if isinstance(x,list))`

Comment: As schwobaseggl and Andreas provided the best answers, I wanted to share a beginner friendly syntax to help better understand this recursive function. However I won't mind deleting my answer if it's juged useless

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Pure recursive approach without loop):

```
def counter(lst, index, count):
    
    if lst[index] == ']' and index == len(lst)-1:
        print(count-1)
    
    else:
        if lst[index] == '[':
            count += 1
        index += 1
        counter(lst, index, count)
```

Driver:

```
nested_list = [[['c', 'x'], ['g', 'ad']], [['a', 'bb'], ['c', 'a']]]
counter(str(nested_list), index=0, count=0)
```

Output:

```
6
```